# Updating a ListBox with different Content On Button Clicks in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

So I have a listbox and a tool bar in my WPF app.  The tool bar just has regular  controls, and the listbox has vertical expanders.

I need the listbox to have a different set of expanders depending on what button is clicked.  Right now it looks like such:

```
<ListBox>
    <local:Select_Analysis_Panel/>
</ListBox>
```

Where `local:Select_Analysis_Panel` is seperate user control file containing the expanders.  What is the best way to go about dynamically updating the ListBox control's content upon a button click?

For the last couple hours I've been trying to use set DataTemplates for each expander set and bind the to the items control property with little avail with the code below.  I'm just trying to get basic framework laid out before setting up a MVVM interface. Later on I was going to replace the `ItemsSource="Network_anal"` with you know `ItemsSource="{Binding WhatExpanderViewModelProperty}"` or something like that.

```
 <ListBox Width="250"  Margin="5,0,0,0">
            <ListBox.Resources>

                <DataTemplate DataType="Select_Analysis_Panel">
                    <local:Select_Analysis_Panel/>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="Network_anal" DataType="NetworkAnalysis">
                    <local:NetworkAnalysis/>
                </DataTemplate>.Resources>

            <ListBox.Template>                    
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Red"/>
                </ControlTemplate>                    
            </ListBox.Template>

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="Network_anal"/>
</ListBox>
```

Am I taking the right approach to this at all?

Here's what I'm trying to do.  Below when the "File" button is clicked the side bar displays these 2 expanders:

[image]
And when "Network Design" button these expanders are dipslayed:

[image]

Comment: Once again, post a screenshot of what you need...

Comment: by the way, how did everything go with the "Nodes Editor"?

Comment: Very very very very well thanks to you, still using your template, it's awesome.  Getting a screen shot now

Comment: wow.... I like that a LOT

Comment: Yea it's been coming along bro! You're advice on using MVVM has been extremely helpful

Comment: that basically would be the same functionality as a `TabControl`... right?

Comment: Yea pretty much.  Originally I used tab control but the map needs to be in every tab and when you have over 1000 UI elements there is a noticeable difference in performance when there are 5 instances of the same control.  Also we needed to do some more custom stuff with enabling/disabling tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Subclassing the sections:

each of these sections could be subclassed from a base section class and a specific `DataTemplate` could be used for each:

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.MultiToolbar"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MiscSamples"
        Title="MultiToolbar" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSection}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                 DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="40"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"/>
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
        
        <ScrollViewer Width="300" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedSection}">
                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileSection}">
                        <TextBlock Text="User Control For File Section"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NetworkDesignSection}">
                        <TextBlock Text="User Control For Network Design"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SelectAnalysisSection}">
                        <TextBlock Text="User Control For Select Analysis"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </ScrollViewer>
        
        <Grid Background="Gray">
            <TextBlock Text="Design Surface" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MultiToolbar : Window
    {
        public MultiToolbar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var vm = new MainViewModel();
            vm.Sections.Add(new FileSection() {Name = "File"});
            vm.Sections.Add(new NetworkDesignSection() { Name = "Network Design" });
            vm.Sections.Add(new SelectAnalysisSection() { Name = "Select Analysis" });

            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
```

Main ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel: PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Section> _sections;
        public ObservableCollection<Section> Sections
        {
            get { return _sections ?? (_sections = new ObservableCollection<Section>()); }
        }

        private Section _selectedSection;
        public Section SelectedSection
        {
            get { return _selectedSection; }
            set
            {
                _selectedSection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSection");
            }
        }
    }
```

Sections:

```
public abstract class Section:PropertyChangedBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        private bool _isEnabled = true;
        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get { return _isEnabled; }
            set
            {
                _isEnabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
            }
        }

        private bool _isVisible = true;
        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get { return _isVisible; }
            set
            {
                _isVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }

        //Optionally
        //public string ImageSource {get;set;}
        //ImageSource = "/Resources/MySection.png";
    }

    public class FileSection: Section
    {
        ///... Custom logic specific to this Section
    }

    public class NetworkDesignSection:Section
    {
        ///... Custom logic specific to this Section
    }

    public class SelectAnalysisSection: Section
    {
        ///... Custom logic specific to File Section
    }

    //...etc etc etc
```

Result:

[image]

Notice that I'm using `ToggleButton`s bound to the `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` property to simulate a `TabControl`-like behavior.

Comment: Haha you accepted the answer and did not give me time to add option 2!!! It was about putting an `IEnumerable<SectionOption>` in the sections and use that to render the `Expanders` and `CheckBoxes` and other stuff.

Comment: Thank you much sir. This will do fine I believe... it's going to look awesome!

Comment: Hey I may have jumped the gun a little bit... If you still have the code could you show me the other way?  Don't bother if it's inconvenient... I got option 1 working fine, it's just going to be slightly difficult to implement something similar for the other panel (There is going to be another panel on the right side that has a different set of button for every check box on the left!)

Comment: @SteelNation I think that's complex enough to deserve a separate question, don't you think? post a new question and let me know! =)

Comment: Alright re-posted here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935011/better-way-to-set-the-content-of-a-control-than-binding-a-class-to-selector-cont

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `DataContext` of the whole form and bind the `ItemsSource` of the `listbox`, or set `ItemsSource` of the `listbox` to some collection directly.