# Better way to set the content of a control than binding a class to selector control in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have an app that is split into 4 panels.  There is a main drawing area, a top panel, a left menu panel, and a right sub menu panel as in the picture below.  The content of the sub menu is determined by what top-menu button is selected, and the content of the sub-menu is determined by what right menu is selected.

For example this is what is displayed when Network Design and test (first button on expander) is clicked.  When test2 (second button on expander) is clicked, there should be a different set of buttons in the right hand panel.

I'm not using tab control because of performance issues with the map, with 10,000+ potential graphics objects already I don't want to go multiplying that number by 8.

I'm currently doing it as stated in this post:

[Updating a ListBox with different Content On Button Clicks in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908243/updating-a-listbox-with-different-content-on-button-clicks-in-wpf/15910760?noredirect=1#comment22698161_15910760)

This has worked great thus far...l but each of those drop down menus may have as many as 8 options, and some of the top tabs have as many as 8 expanders!  Using the above code would take alot of work... hopefully there is a more 'terse' way of going about it.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? I don't fully understand the relation between right and left panels.

Comment: Sure, updating now.  They more or less have the same relation as the top and right panel

Comment: Ok updated it.  Let me know if I did/didn't get the point across

Comment: Those in the right are all buttons, right? is there anything else you'll place in there, or it will be just buttons? you can create an `ObservableCollection<DelegateCommand>` to dynamically show / hide these buttons (and bind them to actions in the ViewModel)

Comment: Only in that version of the panel... but there are going to have to be text boxes, combo boxes, other more complicated controls in some of the others.

Comment: then you're going to need specific ViewModels for each, conceptually the same as the `Sections` sample.

Comment: It would be best if I could set a <local:TheUserControl/> to appear when a certain button is clicked as you showed me earlier.  The thing with have instances of a 'Section' class is that I have less control over there properties since each separate one is not defined in xaml.  That is a problem because a very important feature I need is being able to have the expanders/tabitems enabled or disabled depending on what checkboxes are clicked.

Comment: Oh man... this is going to be difficult

Comment: You should control the Enabled/Visibility states of these UI elements via `bool` properties in the ViewModel. I don't understand the difficulty... I see it as really Simple.

Comment: That's what I have currently...

Comment: Use an `ItemsControl` to bind these `Expanders` to some Collection in the Sections, then put the Enabled/Visibility States in the ViewModels inside the collection.

Comment: But how would I specify which instance of 'SectionsClass' to that I want to enable and disable?

Comment: You should reference the different ViewModels directly. I mean, `SectionA` may have a reference to `MainViewModel` and do `MainViewModel.Sections[3].IsEnabled = false;`. Otherwise create events or use a messaging pattern

Comment: So I can bind an items control to a specific composite collections of different controls like we did with the nodes/connectors?  But instead of having ListBox.ItemsSource = "Collection"  we have ListBox.ItemsSource = "{Static Resource {binding DataContext.SelectedSubMenu, Source={x:Reference main}}}"

Comment: I know you said ItemsControl not ItemsSource, that was just the closet thing I could compare it too haha

Comment: yeah, basically an `ItemsControl` is the base class for all item-capable UI elements in WPF (`ListBox`, `Menu`, `ComboBox`, `TabControl`, etc). It supports defining `ItemTemplate` and so on

Comment: Ok I think I got it. The thing I struggle with most is how wpf knows which control to display, like in the tabs we have class's bound to each button so if that button is clicked it sets the SelectedSection property the appropriate SectionDataType.  I don't know how I'd port that to having the expanders clicked...

Comment: Wait so did you mean I could manually set SelectedSection property via setting a click or checked event and throwing `MainViewModel.SelectedSection = CorrectInstanceOfSectionBlank`?  That would be perfect

Comment: Like the main issue is with what works fine with the tabs is I want to just keep my expanders as regular controls, not define a template for them and hardcode what each property is.  It's fine with the tabs because their simple but there is a lot more going on with the expanders!  Having to hard code all there individual properties in code behind would be a pain. Hopefully the above will work...

Comment: you almost never use code behind in WPF. You can use different `UserControls` for each expander's content. Also, these would have to be represented somehow in the ViewModel layer, you will probably want to define a ViewModel for each.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dedicated ViewModel object for the view. The ViewModel should act as a state machine for different UI states. It should accept Commands and PropertyChanges and as result it would calculate and change his resulting properties to which WPF controls are bound.

It's commonly known as MVVM pattern and is widely used in WPF. The Model is your raw data, the View is your Control and the ViewModel is the state-machine which connects the two. Check out for example [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).