# How to design a TabPage when the TabControl's ItemsSource is Bind to a List in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

**These are my Classes:**

```
   class mainViewModel
    {       
        public List<Foo> F { get; set; }
        public mainViewModel()
        {
        F=new List<Foo>()
              {
                  new Foo(new Animal(){Name = "Cat"}),
                  new Foo(new Animal(){Name = "Dog"}),
                  new Foo(new Animal(){Name = "Camel"})
              };
        }
     }

    public class Foo
    {
        public Animal Animal { get; set; }
        public Foo(Animal animal)
        {
            Animal = animal;
        }
    }

    public class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**And This is my MainWindow Xaml Code:**

```
  <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=F}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Animal.Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Something 1"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
  </TabControl>
```

Now obviously I will have a `TabControl` with one page for each Item in the List `F` and all the `TabControl` pages have a `TextBlock` *Something 1* as shown here:

[image]

**what I want is to design just one of the pages. say add new `button` to the Camel page named *Something 3*.**

Comment: Create a specific ViewModel for each tab, and use `DataTemplates` based on each ViewModel type. See [my example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15910760/643085)

Comment: Just to know if I understood, this line [`<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileSection}">`] tells `WPF` that for all TabPages that is of type T (here FileSection) the DataTemplate will be as following. and I have to add my controls beneath this line. Am I right?

Comment: That's right. Then you create a specific View for each.

Comment: @HighCore Shall I create a `view` for each `ViewModel` or I have to do my designing stuffs beneath the aforementioned line?? If I have to create a View, where shall I set that to be shown in the `TabControl Pages` as I can't see something like this in your Example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the above comments:

Create a specific ViewModel class for each Tab:

```
public class Tab1: ViewModelBase
{
   //... functionality, properties, etc
}

public class Tab2: ViewModelBase
{
   //... functionality, properties, etc    
}

public class Tab3: ViewModelBase
{
   //... functionality, properties, etc    
}
```

Then Create a specific View (usually in the form of UserControls) for each:

```
<UserControl x:Class"UserControl1" ...>
   <!-- UI Elements, etc -->
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class"UserControl2" ...>
   <!-- UI Elements, etc -->
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class"UserControl3" ...>
   <!-- UI Elements, etc -->
</UserControl>
```

Then create `DataTemplates` for each ViewModel Type and put these `UserControls` inside them:

**Edit:** These should be defined in `App.xaml` under `Application.Resources`:

```
<Application ....>
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel1}">
            <local:UserControl1/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel2}">
            <local:UserControl2/>
       </DataTemplate>

       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel3}">
           <local:UserControl2/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Finally, put an `ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>` in your main ViewModel and add these Items:

```
public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> Tabs {get;set;} //Representing each Tab Item

public MainViewModel() //Constructor
{
    Tabs = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();
    Tabs.Add(new ViewModel1());
    Tabs.Add(new ViewModel2());
    Tabs.Add(new ViewModel2());
}
```

Comment: Sorry @HighCore but I am new to `WPF`. What do you mean by `create DataTemplates for each ViewModel Type and put these UserControls inside them`? how can I create DataTemplates for a ViewModel?? Actually I don't know where I should write these Lines `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel1}">
    <local:UserControl1/>
</DataTemplate>`

Comment: Puff!!! Finally worked. I put these lines everywhere in my Application but it didn't work ;) @HighCore you are a life saver :)

Comment: what does this ViewModelBase.cs consists of ?

Comment: @Sss http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/NET35/html/e1c28204-2508-66c2-f984-25ba65c04a30.htm