# Getting access to a Tab Control in a View Model class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, tabcontrol

I have a `View Model` that controls a `Tree View`. Also in my GUI is a `Tab Control` that is not controlled by the `View Model`. If I want to use the `Tree View` to access elements of the `Tab Control` how would I give my `View Model` access to it (the `Tab Control`)?

I'm guessing it would be something along the lines of how I pass a selected item from the `Tree View` from code-behind to the `View Model`.

Code-Behind:

```
//Gets selected item in TreeView
private void Tree_One_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
       MainWindowViewModel.SelectedItem = e.NewValue as TreeViewItem;
}
```

`View Model`:

```
public static TreeViewItem SelectedItem { get; set; } //Selected Node\
```

---

**My current attempt**

Code-Behind:

```
MainWindowViewModel.middleControl = tabControl1 as TabControl;
```

`View Model`:

```
public static TabControl middleControl { get; set; }
```

The following doesn't work because the `View Model` still does not see the any of the items inside the `Tab Control`

```
if (parent_Node.Items.Contains(SelectedItem))
                middleControl.SelectedIndex = nameOfTabItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access view elements from other classes in the project you can query the window. When my `SelectedItem` changes I call to a function in my `View Model` that queries the window and then proceeds to perform operations.

Yes - I know this is not proper `MVVM` etiquette, but it works, and it provides a solution to my question.

Code-Behind:

```
//Gets selected item in TreeView
private void Tree_One_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
       MainWindowViewModel.SelectedItem = e.NewValue as TreeViewItem;
       MainWindowViewModel.changeTab();
}
```

`View Model`:

```
//Controls the changing of tabs, corresponding with the selected TreeViewItem
public static void changeTab()
{
    //Query for Window1
    var mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows
        .Cast<Window1>()
        .FirstOrDefault(window => window is Window1) as Window1;

    //Change selected tab item
    if (parent_Node.Items.Contains(SelectedItem)) 
         mainWindow.TabItem.IsSelected = true;

    //other operations....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The view model should not use the Tab control directly. The whole purpose of MVVM architecture is separation of the UI and business logic. Only the view should access the controls in the UI, and even then that is rarely necessary due to data binding and the logic in the view model.

Why is the tab control not managed by the view model?

Also the view model shouldn't know anything about TreeViewItems - it should operate on the model class that is bound to each item in the tree.

Comment: The `tab control` is not managed by the `view model` because I used the design window to create and place items on it. I think it would be a lot harder to create such a detailed `tab control` with a model.

Comment: @EricAfterDark See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17954320/643085) about how to deal with a TabControl in MVVM.

Comment: @Ericafterdark It is harder to use a tab control with MVVM than a tree or list control, but it can be done. HighCore's answer describes the process quite well.

Comment: I really need a spot where I can see the Tree View and the Tab Control at the same time.

Comment: @Ericafterdark couldn't you use your view for that? Although it sounds like you might be doing too much work in the view, and not enough in the view model or with bindings.

Comment: Well right now it looks like I have my `Tab Control` in my `View Model`. Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the `tab items` that belong to the control.

Comment: @Ericafterdark it's hard to say without seeing the code for what you're trying to do, but you shouldn't use the `TabControl` directly from the view model. It's a much better design to expose a collection property, and bind that to the `ItemsSource` of the `TabControl`.

Comment: I posted some code in my question. Can I do that with my `TabControl` defined inside my View?